# Only allow Application server IP or WFE server also?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, smtp, application-server

We have two load balanced WFEs and two application servers.

Email was not being sent even though SMTP is defined in central administration. Turns out Exchange (or probably firewall) was blocking it. We have added Application server IP in allowed list but still email is not being sent.

My question is do we also need to allow WFE IPs? Because I suppose email is sent by Application server right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to allow the WFE to relay emails through Exchange as well.

Some emails are actually sent by timer jobs in SharePoint, for example there is a timer job called "Immediate Alerts" which sends email to users who have registered for alerts on lists/libraries. Depending on configurations made SharePoint could pick any of your servers to run timer jobs from, which then results in the email being sent from whatever server runs the Timer Job for a certain occasion.